# Kobo Aura SE: Images and dark mode is not shown correctly

Tags: kobo

that's more than a year that I have this problem.
First of all my device is Kobo Aura 2nd edition (that little one), I can remember my kobo was working fine I had recognized that when I connected my kobo to PC. At this time colors get inverted typically and show the computer icon, but that time did not.
This also happens for images when they are too dark.

I tried to install and check it with Koreader and the problem was there, I'm sure that the problem is not from software:  [#6278](https://github.com/koreader/koreader/issues/6278)
Let get more info about it:
That the typical situation which works well:
[image]
When the dark mode is active:
[image]
There is no contrast.

Video:
[image]

Another situation that I need to mention, when white is enough (happens when there is an image) dark mode works well:
[image]
[image]
The image does not have enough detail indeed.

With all of these things, Can anybody say what is the problem? Im sure it is from hardware but how it can be repaired?